# Including an external jQuery file in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

So guys, I guess my question is quite understandable: I want to include an external jQuery file into my HTML. I tried many many ways, which I thought (and still think) were correct, but it doesn't seem to be so.

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pinkmoon.js"></script>
```

Where pinkmoon.js is the file that holds my jQuery.

Comment: what's the error? is the file inside js dir and named exactly pinkmoon.js? make sure that you have index.html/js/pinkmoon.js

Comment: Looks like a path issue. Try having them in the same directory as your HTML file (and delete `js/`s from the HTML file)?

Comment: Is there a directory named `js/`?

Comment: When opening the page source and clicking on the paths (links) they open and it shows me the jQuery/Javascript code, which means the paths are correct.

Comment: @Dugi in that case, it should be fine. What doesn't work?

Comment: @Dugi - you have yet to tell us what should happen, and what is or is not happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you navigated to a page that physically resides in a folder structure like so:

`http://mywebsite.com/folder1/subfolder1/myPage.html`

Then with your current code the source is going to look like this:

`src="http://mywebsite.com/folder1/subfolder1/js/pinkmoon.js"`

Which is not what you want. What you do want is this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pinkmoon.js"></script>`

Which would infer that the physical location of `pinkmoon.js` resides at:

`http://mywebsite.com/js/pinkmoon.js`

Comment: As I said, once I open the page source, and found the js/pinkmoon.js and click on it, it opens a new code window with all my jQuery, which means I navigated in the right path.

Comment: @Dugi, so obviously however your referencing code is incorrect, thus not working. Do you have functions in there that you call within the page?

Comment: No, there are no Javascript functions that are being called by events (onclick etc.) just pure code that works with HTML attributes (mostly ids).

Comment: @Dugi, it's hard to tell without seeing the code. Is the code you want to run on page load wrapped in `$(function(){ });`?

Comment: I got it fixed in some way. Thanks for your help :D.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Be sure to have the file you want to include in a directory called "js" at the same level of you html file.

For exemple :

```
mysite/index.html
mysite/js/pinkmoon.js
```