# Linking JQuery File to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, this is going to sound very imbecilic. (which it probably is)
I'm a very novice programmer, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to link a simple jQuery file to my HTML file, but I can't seem to make it work. After looking through the previous answers to this trivial question, I realized that i was missing pivotal lines of code such as (and this is just an example)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Again, I know I must sound very stupid.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firststuffcss.css"/>
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
</body>
```

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#green').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Can someone please tell me how to link the jQuery file to the HTML file? I know this question has been asked 500 times, but for some reason I am unable to make this work. Thank you very much! Sorry for making you cringe with my ineptness.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332752/including-an-external-jquery-file-in-html

Comment: ug. It still isn't working. 
Could someone post a working js fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your initial jquery load to the header beneath the stylesheets. You want to load any css before you load your jquery scripts (in the future).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>     
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
    #green {width: 150px; height: 150px; background: green; }
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#green').fadeOut(1000);
});

});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="green"></div>

</body>
```

Do note that you load jquery *before* you use any part of the script calls (`$`).

Hope that helps!

Here's your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2633c1em/

Comment: AHHH IT STILL ISN'T WORKING 
could someone please please please please please post a working js fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

First of all its is **mandatory** to include **jQuery library**.
There are few ways you can link your jQuery code in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firststuffcss.css"/> 
    <!-- Mandatory to include -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

This is how you can integrate your codes:

**Method 1 (In Footer)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firststuffcss.css"/> 
    <!-- Mandatory to include -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#green').fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Method 2 (In Header)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firststuffcss.css"/> 
    <!-- Mandatory to include -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#green').fadeOut(1000);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Method 3 (From External File)**  Lets say you have a file custom.js that has you codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#green').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

This is how you can add external js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="firststuffcss.css"/> 
    <!-- Mandatory to include -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="PATH_OF_JS_FILE/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Update: Path Example**

```
- Project Directory
--- CSS
--- CSS/style.css
--- JS
--- JS/custom.js
--- index.php | index.html

url: http://www.yourproject.com
js path: http://www.yourproject.com/JS/custom.js
```

Comment: so is the 
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
universal for all computers? Like would it work for anyone?

Comment: Also, could you give me syntax for "path of the js file?" Thank you so much

Comment: @NeilnGauss yes it works for all computer and devices as well such as tablet, mobile also. Path stands for the location of your file.

Comment: wait so could you give me an example of syntax? for path?

Answer (score 0):

Put your script tag in header section like

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your jquery file name "></script>
</head>
```

file name like load.js